# javascript code error syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax

i think that i have a sintax error in this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send").submit(function() {
            $.post("validation.php", {
                nameRegist: $('#nameRegist').val(),
                emailRegist: $('#emailRegist').val(),
                myPasswordRegist: $('#myPasswordRegist').val(),
                pass2Regist: $('#pass2Regist').val()

            }, function(data) {
                if (data == 'nomeInvalido') {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Nome inválido').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                } else if (data != 'emailValido' || data != 'emailRegistado') {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Email inválido').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                } else if (data == 'passInvalida') {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Pass inválida').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                } else if (data == 'dadosInvalidos') {
                    $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('Dados inválidos').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
            }
            } else {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Registo Efectuado.....').addClass('messageboxok1').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                        document.location = 'emprego.php';
                    });
                }
            return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

I'm completely lost in quotes

if someone can help me, i really appreciate

thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no but i check in this online tool and give me errors http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php and the script don't do what is supposed, so i suspect that is a syntax problem

Comment: "i think?" what makes you doubt?

Comment: i have 99% sure that i have problems in quotes and parenthesis

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you run your code through that javascript validation site?  I use jslint (http://www.jslint.com/) and it gives descriptive, useful error messages.  I see just now you say that you believe you may have some mismatching quotes/parens.  Are you using a text editor which could help you?

Comment: line 28 - SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a number of issues, see comments below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").submit(function() {
        $.post("validation.php", {
            nameRegist: $('#nameRegist').val(),
            emailRegist: $('#emailRegist').val(),
            myPasswordRegist: $('#myPasswordRegist').val(),
            pass2Regist: $('#pass2Regist').val()

        }, function(data) {
            if (data == 'nomeInvalido') {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Nome inválido').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            } else if (data != 'emailValido' || data != 'emailRegistado') {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Email inválido').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            } else if (data == 'passInvalida') {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Pass inválida').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            } else if (data == 'dadosInvalidos') {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Dados inválidos').addClass('messageboxerror1').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
    /////// } extra, remove
            } else {
                $("#msgbox1").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                    $(this).html('Registo Efectuado.....').addClass('messageboxok1').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                        document.location = 'emprego.php';
                    });
                }); /////// missing ");"
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}); ////// missing "});"
```

Comment: if the final `else` is extra, you should change the last `else if` to an else.

Comment: @vol7ron: the `else` is not extra, the close paren is.

Comment: oh .. I like do do inner comments like /* } // this is extra */ - this makes sense then :) lol

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing brace at line 26, this:

```
}
} else {
```

should be just

```
} else {
```

And then you'll want to indent the `} else {` chunk one more step to make things consistent.